# Issue with h2 text being cut off for display on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Sorry, this is driving me crazy, I'm sure its simple but cannot crack it.

As per the screen shot, the text is being cut off for mobile devices, I thought it would be an adjustment in the css here by adjusting margins or borders, but no avail to this. Can someone suggest a solution? or point me to a solution?

View the site here www.yostrato.com

```
#owl-main-text {
    height: 180px;
}

    #owl-main-text h2 {
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
        letter-spacing: 10px;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 7px;
        margin-top: 35px;
        font-family: "Montserrat";
        background-color: rgba(193, 48, 48, 0.79);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: show the rest of the css. the problem is in the containing div.

Comment: Cheers that helped, found it and updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change height to min-height here:

```
#owl-main-text {
    min-height: 180px; /* or whatever value */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by increasing height to 180px:

```
#owl-main-text {
    height: 180px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query to increase the height off the red colored div just before the H2 text starts to get cut off.